# NullReferenceException from ViewData which is Not Null actually

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mm6e6.png)

I think the screenshot explains everything. How can i resolve this problem ? Even the data is not null, it gives null reference exception..

Stacktrace is below:

```
   at ASP._Page_Views_Profile_Index_cshtml.Execute() in c:\aaaaaa\aaa\aaaaaa\Views\Profile\Index.cshtml:line 17
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass1a.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__17()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
```

Comment: Hit view detail and drill down into the exception, maybe can point you (and us) in the right direction.

Comment: The inner exception is null it says :S

Comment: Looking at how Visual Studio hightlighted the code it seems that the issue is elsewhere and it is pointing to this place by error. Try cleaning the solution (from the properties menu), recompiling.

Comment: Cleaning the solution and recompiling it did not work :(

Comment: do you have a display template or editor template which the Phonenumber property is using ?

Comment: Click 'Copy exception details to clipboard' and paste them here

Comment: Nop it is just a string and showing it just right there.

Comment: @Shyju - simple `@variable` will not use templates

Comment: try to comment this line (@* *@) so we can make sure the error is there.

Comment: Can we get the StackTrace from the exception?  Maybe there is something there that is happening in the background that you are not seeing?  That is actually what I ment by "drill down" not just inner exception.

Comment: just put below my question sir.

Comment: @Knaģis is right - the debugger is using a different version of the code to that shown in the editor, hence the unusual highlighting around the error.  What is your full call-stack at the point of the exception?

Comment: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/42/screenshot20121106at606.png/ this is the error when I comment out there.

Comment: Okay i found the bug as you guys have stated before, the bug is elsewhere and debugger is pointing out wrong. Anyway thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm betting for a threading issue. When the ViewEngine tries to display/bind the value(MobilePhone) it's null and it throws the exception but in the meantime the thread responsible for loading the data finishes and when expecting/viewing the value in the debugger the value is present.

Comment: Well actually I'm not loading any data right there. I just put user data which consists of simple properties such as integer and string and showing them...